# Need input in another div! #listjs

Tags: javascript, html, input, listjs

Anyone in here familiar with LISTJS plugin? If so, I require your assistance.

Reffering to: http://codepen.io/javve/pen/zpuKF.

What I'm trying to achieve is NOT havin the search-input within the same div as the list.

I want the search-input in another div. Is this possible? If so, what do I do, I'm guessing I'm gonna have to edit the source code...?

To sum up - I wan't the input field in another div, not the "users" - as described below.

```
 <div id="THIS IS WHERE I WANT MY INPUT FIELD"></div>
 <div id="users">
 <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
 <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
 Sort by name
 </button>

 <ul class="list">
 <li>
  <h3 class="name">Jonny Stromberg</h3>
  <p class="born">1986</p>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h3 class="name">Jonas Arnklint</h3>
  <p class="born">1985</p>
</li>
<li>
  <h3 class="name">Martina Elm</h3>
  <p class="born">1986</p>
</li>
<li>
  <h3 class="name">Gustaf Lindqvist</h3>
  <p class="born">1983</p>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
<script src="http://listjs.com/no-cdn/list.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by editing the plugin, only some few lines of code to add some options to the plugin to make it accept sibling search input by `id`

1. First go to the **init()** method in the plugin to add some options and their default values, let say `options.searchWithId` which is a boolean that indicates if you want sible search input using an `id` and `options.searchId` which correspond to the Id of your search input:

   ```
   // If not provided in the options it takes false by default
   self.searchWithId = options.searchWithId || false;
   // In case search input with id, initialise the id
   self.searchWithId ? self.searchId = options.searchId || false : void 0;
   ```
2. After that you need to modify the input search object retrieval by adding those lines of code, just before the `keyup` event bind:

   ```
   var searchInput = null;
   if(list.searchWithId === false){
       searchInput = getByClass(list.listContainer, list.searchClass);
   }
   else{
       searchInput = $("#"+list.searchId);
   }
   ```
3. And finally change the events binding like this:

   ```
   events.bind(searchInput, 'keyup', function(e) {
       var target = e.target || e.srcElement, // IE have srcElement
           alreadyCleared = (target.value === "" && !list.searched);
       if (!alreadyCleared) { // If oninput already have resetted the list, do nothing
           searchMethod(target.value);
       }
   });

   // Used to detect click on HTML5 clear button
   events.bind(searchInput, 'input', function(e) {
       var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
       if (target.value === "") {
           searchMethod('');
       }
   });
   ```
4. You can initialize your plugin this way:

   ```
   var options = {
     valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ],
     searchWithId: true,
     searchId: "search-list"
   };

   var userList = new List('users', options);
   ```

and you put your search input where you want (outside, inside, ...)

```
<input id="search-list" class="search" placeholder="Search" />
<div id="users">

  <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
    Sort by name
  </button>

  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Jonny Stromberg</h3>
      <p class="born">1986</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Jonas Arnklint</h3>
      <p class="born">1985</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Martina Elm</h3>
      <p class="born">1986</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Gustaf Lindqvist</h3>
      <p class="born">1983</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

I tested it and it works, if you want the entire file just let me know.

**Update**

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ow4eqmc8/)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out! Worked perfectly - thank you!

Comment: This is a great solution but unfortunately it breaks pagination.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you figured out a solution or you implemented the one above. I think that it's not OK to modify a plugin if you have alternatives. I had the same problem and I solved it by using the listObj.search from [list.js documentation](http://www.listjs.com/docs/list-api). The code will look something like this:

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function () {   // #searchInput is your input
    var searchString = $(this).val();   // your searching string
    searchList.search(searchString);    // searchList is your new List
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done like that, otherwise it wont have relation with your code below, that's the reason why you had to include it in your (Div) users, is there any particular reason you trying to put it in a different (DIV)

Answer (score 0):

Search and sort can be triggered via javascript.

Like For search, suppose search input id is mySearch

```
$('#mySearch').on('keyup', function() {
  var searchString = $(this).val();
  userList.search(searchString);
});
```

To search against specific column :

```
    $('#mySearch').on('keyup', function() {
  var searchString = $(this).val();
  userList.search(searchString, ['user']);
});
```

Similarly for sorting use sort function :

```
$('#mySort').on('click',function() {
    userList.sort('user',{
        order: "desc"
    })
});
```